Error while building astro project, the file path has two 'C:\\C:\\' does this affect something?
I'm currently trying to deploy a website with astro.js. Here's my astro.config file:
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";
import tailwind from "@astrojs/tailwind";
import vercel from "@astrojs/vercel/serverless";
import solidJs from "@astrojs/solid-js";
import compress from "astro-compress";
import critters from "astro-critters";
import sitemap from "@astrojs/sitemap";
import favicons from "astro-favicons";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  output: "server",
  site: "https://dungeonradioclub.com/",
  integrations: [
    tailwind(),
    solidJs(),
    compress(),
    critters(),
    sitemap(),
    favicons({
      appName: "Dungeon Radio Club",
      appShortName: "DRC",
      appDescription:
        "dungeonradioclub c:",
      lang: "pt-BR",
      masterPicture: "./src/assets/dungeon_logo_small.svg",
      emitAssets: true,
      faviconsDarkMode: false,
      path: "/",
    }),
  ],
  adapter: vercel(),
});

And here's the output I'm getting when npm run build has started:

01:30:31 PM [content] No content directory found. Skipping type generation.
01:30:31 PM [build] output target: server
01:30:31 PM [build] deploy adapter: @astrojs/vercel/serverless
01:30:31 PM [build] Collecting build info...
01:30:31 PM [build] Completed in 174ms.
01:30:31 PM [build] Building server entrypoints...
node:internal/process/promises:288
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\C:\Users\rhamo\Documents\GitHub\dungeon-ui\public'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'mkdir',
path: 'C:\C:\Users\rhamo\Documents\GitHub\dungeon-ui\public'
}
Node.js v18.20.3

I was expecting getting a dist folder so I can upload the files via ftp

sounds like a bug, but difficult to say for sure. you should try to create a minimal reproducible example. that way you'll know what part of the code or config causes the error. also make sure you're using the latest version of all packages (and preferably also latest node.js LTS)

Note: because of adapter: vercel(), you can only upload to vercel. just remove that if you want to get a bunch of html files you can upload via ftp. see https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/deploy/
